# C# What pattern to use to create a type based on different types?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have three different objects which act as input to create object A. The three different objects are:

- DataRow
- object A (when I want to create a copy)
- Object B (looks like object A, but is different and not a subtype)

Now I have a static method on object A that looks like this:

```
public class ObjectA
{
   // class code

   public static ObjectA CreateFromType(DataRow row) {/*implementation */}
   public static ObjectA CreateFromType(ObjectA obj) {/*implementation */}
   public static ObjectA CreateFromType(ObjectB obj) {/*implementation */}
}
```

Is this a good way? Is this a code smell that violates OCP? How would you implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not provide appropriate constructors instead of factory methods? Is there a fourth scenario where `ObjectA` can be "default-created"?

Constructors have a definite advantage as an approach in that they are the most visible part of `ObjectA`'s public interface when someone is about to create one. If the main scenario for instances is to be created in one of the ways you mention, I 'd stronly suggest constructors.

A special mention for the "clone" constructor: if you have other classes in your assembly which are clonable, it might make sense to define your own `IClonable` derivative as well with well-defined semantics (shallow or deep clone) and use that approach instead of the copy constructor.

Comment: I agree. Create overloaded constructors, each accepting a different object type as an argument.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just create different constructors on `ObjectA`? Or explicit or implicit operators? I don't see the need for static methods in your case.

Answer (score 2):

Looks OK, though you could also use constructors

```
public class ObjectA
{
   // class code

   public ObjectA(DataRow row) {/*implementation */}
   public ObjectA(ObjectA obj) {/*implementation */}
   public ObjectA(ObjectB obj) {/*implementation */}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can `ObjectA` be created on its own and initialized independently?  I would be inclined to leave your constructor devoid of this data transfer, and instead create object methods to initialize the data for your 3 different scenarios.

This also improves flexibility should you wish to inherit from ObjectA and specialize the data transfer.

Comment: Yes, objectA can be created on its own (`ObjectA obj = new ObjectA`).